# Facing issue with c:out tag in Spring Application

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have problem with the  tag.

### **Controller Code**

```
List<Book> searchResultList = bookService.searchBook(bookBean.getSearchText());

ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView("searchResults");

if (null!=searchResultList)
{           
    modelView.addObject("searchResultList", searchResultList);

    System.out.println("========"+searchResultList.get(0).getBookTitle());

    return new ModelAndView("searchResults");
}
```

### **JSP Code**

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResultList}" var="res">           
    <p>${res.bookTitle}</p>     
</c:forEach>
```

### **Issue**

I am able to get the record printed in the controller code.
But it is not being printed from the JSP.
I searched through the forums, tried different solutions, but not able to resolve.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Are you getting any exception on page load?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some syntax error in your foreach loop. Try below code snippet:

```
<c:forEach items="${searchResultList}" var="res">

  <p><c:out value="${res.bookTitle}" /></p>

</c:forEach>
```

Also for this to work you have to include below tag library in your JSP page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

If facing issue let me know.

You have a problem in the code. After printing the `ArrayList` as `System.out.println("========...`, when you are returning `ModelAndView` object you are creating a new one this will return a new object, not the one in which you are setting the `ArrayList` object.

Please return the `modelView` variable. See below code snippet:

```
if (null!=searchResultList){            
    modelView.addObject("searchResultList", searchResultList);

    return modelView;
}
```

Add `spring-expression` dependency in your pom.xml file. Keep the version same as other Spring module dependency. See below code snippet:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>${same as other spring module}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Tried the above solution. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: I had already included the tag lib..I doubt it is the issue with the java code, I mean setting to the model

Comment: I had already included the tag lib..I doubt it is the issue with the java code, I mean setting to the model, But not able to figure out

Comment: Edited the answer please check.

Comment: Please check if you are returning modelAndView in which you set the `searchResultList` and check in jsp page `c:out` tag. Also check `taglib`.

Comment: I just removed all the codes. Tried the below code:

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/login")
 public ModelAndView login() {

  ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("success");
  mv.addObject("welcomeMessage", "Welcome to my Application");
  return mv;
 } In success.jsp <html>
<body>
 <center><h1>${welcomeMessage}</h1></center>
<h2>Success</h2>
</body>
</html> The Page shows : ${welcomeMessage} and not the message